# Using another function on modified dictionary

Tags: python, beginner, python-3.x

This is based upon an exercise in chapter 5 of *Automate the Boring Stuff with Python*.

This code contains functions `addToInventory` which modifies a given inventory of items to add new items as well as update  existing items and `displayInventory` which displays the items and their values. The main operation is adding the contents of a list `dragonloot` to inventory `inv`.

I have tried to do this in two ways, one by calling `addToInventory` and after that calling `displayInventory`. This method leads to errors. Another way I tried was by printing the new inventory values within `addtoInventory`. This works fine. Why doesn't the first method work? I have put both the methods as comments within my code, indicated by `""" """`.

I know C++ pretty well, but I'm new to Python. Expected result: 
Inventory:
gold coin: 45 rope:1 dagger:1 ruby:1 Total number of items is 48

```
def addToInventory(inventory, addedItems):
    draft = {}
    for i in addedItems:
        if (i not in draft):
            draft[i]=1
        else:
            draft [i]= draft [i] + 1
    for i in draft:
        if i not in inventory:
            inventory[i]=draft[i]
        else:
            inventory[i] = inventory[i]+draft[i]
    """for i in inventory:
        print(str(inventory[i]) + " " + str(i))"""


def displayInventory(inventory):
    print ("Inventory: ")
    total=0
    for i in inventory.items():
        total+=1
        print (str(inventory[i])+" "+str(i))
    print("Total number of items is"+str(total))


    inv = {'gold coin': 42, 'rope': 1}
    dragonLoot = ['gold coin', 'dagger', 'gold coin', 'gold coin', 'ruby']
    inv = addToInventory(inv, dragonLoot)
    """displayInventory(inv) when I use this line in place of above comment I get errors"""
```

Comment: please add the expected result to your code. What will inventory be after you performed your function?

Comment: Please note that explaining your own code to you is usually considered [off-topic](/help/dont-ask) here on Code Review.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know, in case I have doubts in my code is there any chat or somewhere where I could ask?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You overwrite inv with the return value of addToInventory

```
inv = addToInventory(inv, dragonLoot)
```

Yet add to inventory does not return anything. 
In order to first get your code to work, just return the inventory:

```
def addToInventory(inventory, addedItems):
    draft = {}
    for i in addedItems:
        if (i not in draft):
            draft[i]=1
        else:
            draft [i]= draft [i] + 1
    for i in draft:
        if i not in inventory:
            inventory[i]=draft[i]
        else:
            inventory[i] = inventory[i]+draft[i]
    return inventory
```

And then lets improve that function using the [collections](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html) library such as:

```
from collections import Counter

def addToInventory(inv, loot):
    loot_counter = Counter(loot)
    return dict(loot_counter + Counter(inv))
```

Further, for the second displayInventory function, you iterate over dict.items(), yet you then try to use the item itself as an index. Instead iterate over dict.keys() and you will be fine:

```
def displayInventory(inventory):
    print ("Inventory: ")
    total=0
    for i in inventory.keys():
        total+=1
        print (str(inventory[i])+" "+str(i))
    print("Total number of items is"+str(total))
```